# I2C Motor Driver (TB6612FNG) and DC fan error

Tags: motor

I running the following code with Seeeduino Cortex M0, DC fan  and Grove - I2C Motor Driver (TB6612FNG) but I get error ,any idea why?

Code:

```
#include "Grove_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG.h"
#include <Wire.h>

MotorDriver motor;

void setup()
{
    // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    motor.init();
}

void loop()
{
    // drive 2 dc motors at speed=255, clockwise
    Serial.println("run at speed=255");
    motor.dcMotorRun(MOTOR_CHA, 255);
    delay(1000);
     
}
```

Errors:

```
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp: In static member function 'static int8_t I2Cdev::readBytes(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t*, uint16_t)':
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp:276:62: error: 'BUFFER_LENGTH' was not declared in this scope
             for (uint8_t k = 0; k < length; k += min(length, BUFFER_LENGTH)) {
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp:276:62: note: suggested alternative: 'REG_DSU_LENGTH'
             for (uint8_t k = 0; k < length; k += min(length, BUFFER_LENGTH)) {
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                              REG_DSU_LENGTH
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp: In static member function 'static int8_t I2Cdev::readWords(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint16_t*, uint16_t)':
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp:416:70: error: 'BUFFER_LENGTH' was not declared in this scope
             for (uint8_t k = 0; k < length * 2; k += min(length * 2, BUFFER_LENGTH)) {
                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\Users\alirazi\Desktop\libraries\Grove_-_Motor_Driver_TB6612FNG\I2Cdev.cpp:416:70: note: suggested alternative: 'REG_DSU_LENGTH'
             for (uint8_t k = 0; k < length * 2; k += min(length * 2, BUFFER_LENGTH)) {
                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                      REG_DSU_LENGTH

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

Comment: it tells you why on the second line of the error message

Comment: This is the example from the Grove - I2C Motor Driver (TB6612FNG) library, any idea how to solve it?
adding #define BUFFER_LENGTH 132 dows not work